# Context Rendering in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, render

I am new in django.So while i was practising django template in shell i saw two different output of "render()" .So here it goes.

```
from django.template import Template,Context
t = Template("My name is {{name}}.")
c = Context("name":"sraban")
t.render(c)
```

So while i hit enter in shell it shows

```
u'My name is sraban'
```

But while i wrote

```
from django.template import Template,Context
t = Template("My name is {{name}}.")
c = Context("name":"sraban")
print t.render(c)
```

It's output is

```
My name is sraban
```

So I want to know what is that extra "u" in the first output and why two output varies???
I use django1.6 in python 2.7.3 .

Answer (score 0):

The `u` means the string is a unicode string. This is called a [`string prefix`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings). The reason it appears in the first example is that the default way to represent a value in the interactive shell is to use the value the function `repr` returns when called with that value as argument. The second example is missing the prefix because `print` doesn't use the `repr`-representation for strings, but their actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing kroolik answer:

If you take a look closer you will notice that the `u` is not the unique difference, in the second output there is no `'` characters.

The difference has to do with the use of two different functions: `repr` and `str`-- as kroolik pointed out-- you can read about them here: [Input and Output](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Taken from Python Doc.

> The **str()** function is meant to return **representations of values** which are fairly human-readable, while **repr()** is meant to generate **representations which can be read by the interpreter** (or will force a SyntaxError if there is no equivalent syntax). For objects which don’t have a particular representation for human consumption, str() will return the same value as repr().

So, that's why you see the `'u'` the interpreter needs to know if a string is unicode or not and thats the way it does it.

At this point it must be obviuos to you that the function: `Template.render` use the `repr()` function while `print` doesn't.