# Django File Field in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to display an HTML file that I upload in a model.  At present, using the `{{ object.file.url }}` syntax simply displays the path to the file.  I would like to display the file itself.

The only additional pieces are that I have addressed my `MEDIA_ROOT` and I have added to my urls:

```
 if settings.DEBUG:
       urlpatterns += 
       static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
       urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Right now, the url displays literally as `folder/file.html`.  Want to use the file as part of both a list and detail view with the larger model.

Comment: I guess you wants to render the HTML `file` and then `response` to the browser. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I want to have a detail view that renders the file

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750739/context-rendering-in-django#25750850

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure I understand how this would work when using a generic view.  Where do I put the `render`?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but at least you should get the idea.
Suppose you have `FielField` and you needs to render the value from `record`. You might need to use `Class-Based` Views since it has many ready-made features.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models


class DjFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

# Function-Based View
from djfiles.models import DjFile


def dj_view(request, pk=None):
    """Get the record and render the `file`"""
    obj = get_object_or_404(DjFile, pk=pk)
    return render(request, obj.file, {
        'title': obj.title
    }, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```